# iphone secure network identification

Tags: iphone, security, wifi, wpas

can anyone tell me (code sample woudl be awesome) how to get the the secure wi-fi userid and password for the current logged user on the iphone

for example: 
Wi-fi settings for a network using WPA2 Enterprise (network/username/password)

how can I found out who's logged for said network ??

Thanks in advance!!!
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get that information because it's a major security risk.

Making such information available would make it possible for a malicious app to steal user IDs and passwords that could be used to penetrate protected networks.

Instead, the OS connects the WiFi and makes the socket available to apps but doesn't provide any other information.

Comment: bummer...  thanks for the answer!!!!!  but can I determine what network is the device connected to??  

let's say that I must be connected to the XYZ network and if I am not the application needs to bail out...   is that acceptable behavior??  
BTW: this is for an enterprise app so it makes sense..  :)

Comment: Not sure. See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Introduction.html for info on how to use Bonjour to get info about the network. You can identify servers and the like but I'm not sure about routers as I've never tired to do that.

Comment: thanks for keeping me straight TechZen... I love the site jsut nt familiar with all the bells and whistles!!